# Wie nennt man jemanden, der ständig plant (was auch immer er tut)?

Tags: single-word-request, expression

Da gibt es (laut Google) nur eine Frage (auf Gutefrage.de) mit unbefriedigenden Antworten. Ich bin im englischen StackExchange darauf gestoßen und ich weiß nicht einmal, wie man es auf Deutsch beschreibt.

Am liebsten wäre mir ein zutreffendes Wort (ein Adjektiv wäre gut, wenn es das gibt).

Ich unterscheide hier zwischen Zweierlei.

- Jemand, der das gerne tut (weil er es mag, aber es ist kein Zwang).
- Und jemand, der ein zwanghaftes Verhalten aufweist (*er muss planen, er kann einfach nicht anders*).

Ich suche Bezeichnungen für beide.

Comment: plansüchtig, planungssüchtig, planfreudig, Planer, Planzwang, Planungszwang, planorientiert, unspontan

Comment: @Em1 wow, das ist eine Reihe. Diese klingen aber irgendwie so künstlich. Wird *plansüchtig* tatsächlich verwendet? Ich kann es im Duden nicht finden.

Comment: Ich würde auch planungswütig und planungsfreudig vorschlagen, bleibe jedoch auf der Suche nach etablieren Begriffen.

Comment: vielleicht irgendwas mit "kalkulieren" oder "Kalkül"? Beispielsweise "kalkulierend" als Adjektiv.

Comment: Perfektionist? Kopfmensch? Jemand, der total verkopft an etwas herangeht?

Comment: @Elyasin Ich glaube keines meiner Vorschläge wird verwendet, bzw. wenn, dann in einem anderen Kontext.

Comment: Ich kenne auch so einen Menschen. Als er sich einmal "richtig anarchisch" geben wollte, schlug er vor: "Wir sollten das mal ganz spontan planen!"

Comment: @cars10 ich brauchte drei anläufe für deinen beitrag. hat sich gelohnt. ausgezeichnet.

Comment: für das zwanghafte Verhalten, käme der Perfektionismus doch sehr nah ran. Wer permanent sein Leben plant, der versucht es zu optimieren/perfektionieren.

Comment: @rob: Perfektionismus ist aber nicht nur rein theoretisch.

Comment: Einige meiner Freunde würden so jemanden als deutsch beschreiben ;)

Comment: Stratege wäre evtl. noch ein mögliches Synonym. Gestalter käme auch in Frage, man könnte auch von einem Pendanten sprechen.

Comment: Jemand der es gerne tut ist ein **Planefroh** (vgl. Sparefroh). Jemand der es zwanghaft machen muss ist ein **Mieseplaner** (vgl. Miesepeter). Und ja, ich habe das selbst erfunden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventuell "sein ganzes [eigenes] Leben verplanen"

> Er hat sein ganzes Leben verplant.

(im Gegensatz zu jemandem , der jemand anderes Leben verplant)

> Sein Vater hat sein ganzes Leben verplant.

Beispiel aus [der FAZ](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/kommentar-wo-ist-nur-die-ganze-zeit-geblieben-13333534.html)

> Vielleicht sollte man sich öfter dafür entscheiden, nicht das ganze Leben zu verplanen, sondern einfach einmal nichts zu tun.

Wenn es ein Wort sein soll:
Vielleicht *Planungsmensch*, oder sogar *Planungstier* ( letzteres auch in Bezug auf Menschen, vgl. Gewohnheitstier). Das ist dann aber eher umgangssprachlich und eher in keinem Wörterbuch zu finden. Grundsätzlich kann man fast beliebig solche Wörter bilden: Planungsfetischist, Planungsfanatiker, Planungsneurotiker...

Comment: Danke für die Redewendung. Ich erhoffte mir ein Wort oder einen Ausdruck.

Comment: + Vorschläge für ein Wort

Answer (score 0):

So wie du den Personentypus beschreibst, würde ich

> Sicherheitsfanatiker

dazu sagen. Das Wort verwendet man zwar auch (und an erster Stelle) für Leute, die ihr Haus, ihr Wohnung, ihr Land oder was auch immer gegen jegliche mögliche Unbill schützen wollen; doch in zweiter Linie meint man damit auch Leute, die bei allem, was sie tun, auf Nummer sicher gehen wollen, und von hier ist der Schritt zum peniblen Vorausplanen nur klein. Darum, denke ich, passt der Begriff auf einen Menschentyp. Wenn ich die Schilderung recht verstanden habe.

Einen Menschen mit gegenteiligem Verhalten, der also auffällig wenig plant und vieles sehr spontan tut, nennt man manchmal (mit verächtlichem Unterton) einen

> Sponti

wobei mir die Wortbildung unklar ist, da es im Deutschen nur wenige Personentypenbezeichnungen mit -i gibt. Vielleicht ist es eine Parallelbildung zu Sozi und Nazi.

Dementsprechend läge es nahe, man spräche beim

> *Planungsfanatiker / *Planfanatiker

von einem

> *Plani

Doch denke ich nicht, dass jemand dieses Wort je schon benutzt hat. (Die Wörter mit Sternchen habe ich hier neu gebildet; sie sind mir bisher ansonsten nicht begegnet.)

Comment: Ist diese Bedeutung von Sponti regional? Normalerweise bezeichnet das doch eine bestimmte Gruppe linker [politischer Aktivisten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponti). Diese zeichnen sich zwar auch in gewisser Weise durch "Spontane Aktionen" aus, aber ich würde das nicht auf einen spontane Personen verallgemeinern. Davon ab ist Planungsfanatiker aber sicherlich eine zutreffende Antwort für den zweiten Teil der Frage.